# How to translate this usage of "afford"

Tags: translation

How does one translate the following sentences?

> I can't *afford* to lose any more time.
>
> I can't afford to lose any more sleep.

I've tried looking this up, but nothing quite matches the meaning I want to convey.

Answer (score 2):

"I can't afford to" can translate directly to " 我（已（经））无法承受……"
I can't afford to lose any more time. 我无法承受损失任何更多的时间。
I can't afford to lose any more sleep. 我无法承受损失任何更多的睡眠。

adding 已 or 已经 enhances the negative tone.

Answer (score 2):

I can't afford to lose any more time.
我不能再损失更多的时间。
我损失不起更多的时间。

I can't afford to lose any more sleep.
我不能再损失更多的睡眠。
我损失不起更多的睡眠。

Comment: 我不能再花费得起任何时间了。我不能再失去任何睡眠了。
(损失 seems to be mainly used as a noun, "cannot afford" often is translated the same as "cannot")

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to translate "afford" into Chinese. Translation may be quite different according to the context.
For your instance, here is my personal suggestion:
我再也耗不起更多时间了。
I can't afford to lose any more time.
I can't afford to consume any more time. (literally)
我不能睡得更少了。
I can't afford to lose any more sleep.
I can't sleep any shorter. (literally, quite different)